# Strike element of array by click on it (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html where I display array from js

Here is code

```
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id ="container">
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input id="text" type=text/>
    <button id="get" onclick="getValue()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Here js code

```
  var tasks = ["Task 1", "Task 2"];
$.each(tasks, function(){
    $('#data').append('<li class="clickable">'+this + '</li>');
});
```

I get  element from list like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
var str =  $(this);

});
```

And now I need to strike it via js. How I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "strike"? Removing it?

Comment: Strike through? or Strike it down ⚡️?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to `strike` the element on click:

```js
var tasks = ["Task 1", "Task 2"];
$.each(tasks, function(){
    $('#data').append('<li class="clickable">'+this + '</li>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

```html
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id ="container">
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input id="text" type=text/>
    <button id="get" onclick="getValue()">Update</button>
</div>
```

But if you want to add and remove strike on click each time then use this:

```js
var tasks = ["Task 1", "Task 2"];
$.each(tasks, function(){
    $('#data').append('<li class="clickable">'+this + '</li>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('strikeClass');
});
```

```css
.strikeClass{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id ="container">
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input id="text" type=text/>
    <button id="get" onclick="getValue()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1) Wrap around `del` tag

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
     var str =  $(this);
     srt.wrap("<del></del>");
});
```

2) Add style attribute

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
     var str =  $(this);
     str.css("text-decoration", "line-through");       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove element, simply do `onClick="$(this).remove();"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  var tasks = ["Task 1", "Task 2"];

  $.each(tasks, function() {
    $('#data').append('<li class="clickable">' + this + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="container">
  <div id="data"></div>
  <input id="text" type=text/>
  <button id="get" onclick="getValue()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i do not understand what you mean

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
 var txt = this.textContent;
this.innerHTML  = txt.strike();
});
```